# How to guard some endpoints with mTLs and some with JWT

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security, java-17

I have a Spring Boot (3.0.5) application - with 3 sets of APIs:

1. `/api/**` - called by a client UI application - uses JWT based authentication
2. `/integration/**` - called by another application - these must be protected with client auth.
3. The rest - publicly accessible.

I am setting `server.ssl.client-auth` to `want` - as I don't need all my endpoints to follow the X502 authentication.

I made it working following a few posts here with similar questions and came up with a security configuration as below. It's working as expected, but as you can see I have to do a lot of custom checks. Is there a better way to achieve this?

This configuration sets `/api/**` to use JWT validation, and the rest is open for public access.

```java
@Bean
public SecurityFilterChain configureSecurityFilters(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
        .authorizeHttpRequests(a -> a
            .requestMatchers(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/api/**")).authenticated()
            .anyRequest().permitAll()
        )
        .csrf().disable()
        .addFilterBefore(jwtValidationFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
    return http.build();
}
```

This is my second configuration, for custom validation of `/integration/**` API calls.

```java
@Bean
@Order(1)
public SecurityFilterChain x502Config(HttpSecurity http, HttpServletRequest request) throws Exception {

    http
        .securityMatcher("/integration/**")
        .csrf().disable()
        .addFilterBefore(customX509AuthenticationFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class)
        .authorizeHttpRequests()
            .anyRequest().permitAll();
    return http.build();
}
```

And this is the custom filter - that validates if a client cert validation occurred and the context has a valid X509 certificate:

```java
import jakarta.servlet.FilterChain;
import jakarta.servlet.ServletException;
import jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import org.apache.commons.lang3.StringUtils;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken;
import org.springframework.security.core.Authentication;
import org.springframework.security.core.context.SecurityContextHolder;
import org.springframework.security.web.util.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher;
import org.springframework.security.web.util.matcher.NegatedRequestMatcher;
import org.springframework.security.web.util.matcher.RequestMatcher;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.security.Principal;
import java.security.cert.X509Certificate;
import java.util.Arrays;

@Component 
public class CustomX509AuthenticationFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {
    
    @Value("${server.ssl.client-auth}") 
    private String mutualTLSConfig;

    @Override 
    protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request,
            HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain filterChain)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        X509Certificate[] clientCertificates = (X509Certificate[]) request.getAttribute(
                "jakarta.servlet.request.X509Certificate");
        if (isMutualTLSEnabled() && (clientCertificates == null
                || clientCertificates.length == 0)) {
            response.sendError(HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED.value(), HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED.name());
            return;
        } else if (isMutualTLSEnabled()) {
            X509Certificate clientCertificate = clientCertificates[0];
            String username = extractUsernameFromCertificate(clientCertificate);
            Authentication authentication = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(username, "",
                    Arrays.asList());
            SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authentication);
        }
        filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
    }

    private String extractUsernameFromCertificate(X509Certificate certificate) {
        Principal principal = certificate.getSubjectDN();
        String name = principal.getName();
        int startIndex = name.indexOf("CN=") + 3;
        int endIndex = name.indexOf(",", startIndex);
        if (endIndex == -1) {
            endIndex = name.length();
        }
        return name.substring(startIndex, endIndex);
    }

        // Ignore this validation if "none" is set (dev purposes)
        // "need" will never be used in this application (because if used, client-auth will be applied to all requests)
    private boolean isMutualTLSEnabled() {
        return StringUtils.isNotEmpty(mutualTLSConfig) && mutualTLSConfig.equalsIgnoreCase("want");
    }

        // I had to add this, otherwise all requests goes through this - which means the "securityMatcher" configuration is not applied properly.
 
    @Override protected boolean shouldNotFilter(HttpServletRequest request) {
        RequestMatcher matcher = new NegatedRequestMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/integration/**"));
        return matcher.matches(request);
    }
}
```

I also have second filter for validating the JWT (`jwtValidationFilter`) for the `/api/**` endpoints.

```java
@Override
protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res,
    FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {

    final String requstUri = req.getRequestURI();
    final String jwtAuthToken = getCookieValue(req, AUTH_TOKEN_COOKIE_NAME);
    // Validates the token and set the authentication in SecurityContextHolder
    ....
    ....
    UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken authentication = getAuthentication(jwtToken, res);
            SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authentication);
    chain.doFilter(req, res);
}
```

This configuration works as expected, but I have a feeling that my security configuration is not perfect.

Using JDK 17, Spring Boot 3.0.5.