# How to enable TLS over all endpoints except for ones that needs mTLS - Spring Boot 3 and Spring Security 6

Tags: java, spring-boot, ssl, spring-security, mtls

I don't need to do any validation over users, etc. I only need that the client send the certificate and the server (me in this case) validate the certificate through truststore or something (apply mTLS in other words).

I have one endpoint, lets say "/authentication", that need to be mTLS, the other ones only need server auth (TLS).

This is a possible solution, I haven't tried it yet, but I think there's a even easier approach

[How to guard some endpoints with mTLs and some with JWT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76187946/how-to-guard-some-endpoints-with-mtls-and-some-with-jwt/78030895#78030895)

For more context if helps, its for 3DS EMVCO

UPDATED STATUS:
made a filter which validates if the request contains at least one certificate.
Combine the filter with ssl.client-auth WANT for a specific route.
(With WANT the certificate will be validated throught truststore)

This is the filter if someone asks:

```
    @Suppress("UNCHECKED_CAST")
override fun doFilterInternal(
    request: HttpServletRequest,
    response: HttpServletResponse,
    filterChain: FilterChain
) {
    try {
        if (isMutualTLSEnabled()) {
            val certificates: Array<X509Certificate>? = request
                .getAttribute("jakarta.servlet.request.X509Certificate") as Array<X509Certificate>?
            if (certificates.isNullOrEmpty()) {

                throw CertificateException()
            }
        }
        filterChain.doFilter(request, response)
    } catch (e: CertificateException) {
        resolver?.resolveException(request, response, null, e)
    }
}
```

If you find some solution like this:
[Implement both mTLS (two way SSL ) and public endpoints (no SSL check)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70589592/implement-both-mtls-two-way-ssl-and-public-endpoints-no-ssl-check)
Is **NOT** what i need, this solution is for **authenticated users**, i will not perform any authentication over USERS